# DevDemon Channel Images Button not showing up in Wygwam

Tags: wygwam, pixelandtonic, channel-images, devdemon

I can't get the channel images button to show up in Wygwam. I'm running EE 2.5.3, Wygwam 2.7, and Channel Images 5.4.2. I have made sure to install the channel images plugin in the themes > third party > wygwam > lib > ckeditor > plugins folder. There are no javascript errors being thrown. I've cleared my cache on browser and ee cms, and tried with a new configuration and existing one. The channel images and wygwam fields are in the same field group. I've performed a "Run Module Updates" in the Modules menu in EE.

I've also noticed another error - which may be with my configuration or with your plugin, where if you go to Admin > Channel Administration > Channel Fields > and edit your wygwam field, then click on "Edit Configurations" under editor configurations,  it takes you to a page that says "the requested module could not be found". But if you go to edit the configurations from Addons > Modules > Wygwam > Editor Configurations - it shows up properly. No errors are thrown in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - figured it out - the channel images button cannot be added to an editor configuration (it doesn't show up) - but it just shows up automatically in the configuration when you edit an entry.

Comment: Im getting this exact problem with EE 2.9 and up to date Wygwam and Channel Images. But I don't understand what you mean about not being able to add the CI icon to the Wygwam CK editor config. I drag the CI icon onto the panel, save the setting (it keeps the CI icon in the tool selection). Then I head over to publish form, no CI icon in the Wygwam field. It just doesn't load. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Update, Ive started a new thread for my problem, [here](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/26965/wygwam-channel-images-and-blocks)