# Wygwam, Channel Images and Blocks

Tags: wygwam, channel-images, blocks

I've looked at a bunch of posts on here but nothing specifically helps with this issue.

Background: I like to offer users rich content choices and have achieved this in the past with a mixture of Matrix and Wygwam, with Assets for images and file downloads, and text areas for embed code. I then build templates and use Template Snippet Select to provide alternate ways of laying out the content page interface (tabs, accordions, page view, etc). Its ok, but with the Blocks module Im hoping to be able to offer this in a much more streamlined way. I'd really like to move to Channel Images because of their in-form image editing and tidy way of organising where images appear in the file manager. So, I contacted Bryan Burgers who built Blocks to ask how CI might integrate - he said it would only work through Wygwam. So, I'm testing a configuration of using Blocks with Wygwam and Channel Images.

*My trouble here is that the Channel Images icon does not appear in the Wygwam CK Editor panel in the publish form, either with or without Blocks. It shows in the config area for Wygwam, but not in the channel field.*

Ive made sure all upload file permissions and urls are correct. What is going on?

**NB Im working in localhost EE 2.9 with CI 5.4 and Wygwam 3.3 (on PC)** but am now trying in a EE2.7 remote environment to run a test there.

[image: Wygwam not showing Channel Images Icon, with and without Blocks]

Comment: Did you add the Channel Images icon in the configuration toolbar setup? You have to add it manually in the 3+ versions.

Comment: yes I added the icon, it shows up in toolbar config. The only way I was able to get it to show up on the toolbar in the publish form was if I used a separate Channel Images field to upload an image, then it would immediately show up, but it would only offer selecting pre-uploaded Channel Images files, and did not offer an upload function. So, useless really.

 I have given up on Blocks/Channel Images and am now using Content Elements which overall is better and works with Assets at least fairly well.

Comment: For information Ive now replaced Wygwam with Editor, a sweeter and better way of providing a wysiwyg, which adds the Channel Images icon easily, but still has the 'no upload function' problem.